# Android can't display some of the images transferred over socket

Tags: java, android, image, imageview

My app sends some text and an image to the other devices in the lan. It looks like images are transmitted and received successfully (I don't get any exception at all) but somehow, some of the images are not displayed well or not displayed at all in the imageView of a CardViewAdapter.

When I receive the image, I create the file and save it with **createFile** method. I transmit also image type and save it with this extension. I don't know what it depends on, but I couldn't resolve it.

**Class that send image over tcp:**

```
    public class ImageTransferHandler implements Runnable{
        private static final String TAG = "ImageTransferHandler";
        private static final int SERVER_PORT = 8700;
        private Socket socket;
        private Context context;
        private String hostIpAddress;
        private Bar bar;

        public ClientThreadProcessor(String hostIpAddress, Context context, Bar bar){
            this.context = context;
            this.hostIpAddress = hostIpAddress;
            this.Bar = bar;
        }

        private Socket getSocket(String hostIpAddress) {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(hostIpAddress);
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT);
            return socket;
        }

        private void closeSocket(Socket socket) {
                    socket.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            socket = getSocket(hostIpAddress);

            OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();


            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                                            new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream)), true);

            output.println(bar.getImageInfo().isCamera());
            Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(bar.getImageInfo().getPath());
            String mimeType = ImagePicker.getMimeType(context, imageUri);
            String ext = mimeType.substring(mimeType.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            if(ext == null) ext = "bmp";
            output.println(ext);
            BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
            String realPath = ImagePicker.getRealPathFromUri(context, imageUri);

            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(realPath);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                bout.write(buffer);
            }
            input.close();
            bout.close();
            Log.d(TAG, "Image sent over network and stream is closed.");                                        

            output.close();

            closeSocket(socket);

        }

    }
```

**Class that receives image over tcp**

```
public class ImageReceiveHandler implements Runnable{
        private static String TAG = "ImageReceiveHandler";
        private Socket socket;
        private Context context;
        private BufferedReader inputBufferedReader;
        private PrintWriter outputPrintWriter;
        private Bar Bar;


        public ClientHandler(Socket socket, Context context){
            this.socket = socket;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

                InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
                inputBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                                        new InputStreamReader(input));

                outputPrintWriter = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

                boolean isCamera = Boolean.valueOf(inputBufferedReader.readLine());
                String ext = inputBufferedReader.readLine();

                File imageFile = ImagePicker.createFile(context, ImagePicker.isExternalStorageWritable(), ext);

                if (imageFile != null) {
                    Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
                    Log.d(TAG, "imageUri for received image: " + imageUri.toString());

                    BufferedInputStream bufin = null;
                    FileOutputStream output = null;

                    bufin = new BufferedInputStream(input);
                    output = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int len;
                    while((len = bufin.read(buffer)) != -1){
                       output.write(buffer);
                       output.flush();
                    }

                    output.close();
                    bufin.close();

                    Log.d(TAG, "Image is received and saved. File length: " + imageFile.length());

                    ImageInfo info = new ImageInfo(imageUri.toString(), isCamera);
                    Bar = new Bar(info);

                    addNotification(Bar, hostAddress);
                }
                else
                    Log.d(TAG, "ImagePicker.createFile returns NULL");


                inputBufferedReader.close();
                outputPrintWriter.close();
        }


        public File createFile(Context context, boolean external, String ext) {
            File direct;

            if(external)
                direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myo_images");
            else
                direct = new File(context.getFilesDir() + "/myo_images");


            if (!direct.exists()) {
                File imagesDir;
                if(external)
                    imagesDir = new File("/sdcard/myo_images/");
                else
                    imagesDir = new File("/myo_images");

                imagesDir.mkdirs();
            }

            String timestamp =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

            File file = null;

            if(external) 
                 file = File.createTempFile("myo_" + timestamp, "." + ext, direct);
            else 
                 file = File.createTempFile("myo_" + timestamp, "." + ext, direct);

            return file;
        }
    }
```

**Adapter class which should visualize images**

```
public class BarsCardViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BarsCardViewAdapter.CardViewHolder> {

        private List<BarData> activeBars;
        private final static String TAG = "CARDVIEW_ADAPTER";


        public BarsCardViewAdapter(List<BarData> Bars){
            activeBars = Bars;
        }

        public static class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            private ActiveBarsListItemBinding listItemBinding;

            public CardViewHolder(View v) {
                super(v);
                listItemBinding = DataBindingUtil.bind(v);
            }

            public ActiveBarsListItemBinding getBinding(){
                return listItemBinding;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public BarsCardViewAdapter.CardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.bars_list_item, parent, false);

            CardViewHolder holder = new CardViewHolder(v);
            return holder;
        }



        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final BarsCardViewAdapter.CardViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            holder.getBinding().imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            final Bar bar  = activeBars.get(position);
            final ImageInfo imageInfo = bar.getImageInfo();
            final LinearLayout rLayout = holder.getBinding().listItemLayout;


            ImageInfo imageInfo = BarData.getImageInfo();
            Log.d(TAG, "imagePath: " + Uri.parse(imageInfo.getPath()));
            holder.getBinding().imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Picasso.with(rLayout.getContext()).
                        load(imageInfo.getPath()).
                        transform(new CropSquareTransformation()).
                        into(holder.getBinding().imageView);


            holder.getBinding().setVariable(BR.Bar, bar);
            holder.getBinding().executePendingBindings();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return activeBars.size();
        }



    }
```

Comment: You only read one line from the inputBufferedReader. Only an ext. But that buffered reader will have buffered much more than that line. It will have buffered a lot of the image too. But you throw that buffer away and try to read the image from a new input. That will not do.

Comment: i removed unnecessary parts but infact i send also some other text before "ext". How should i use streams to send correctly text and after image? how can i avoid buffering image data in the BufferedReader? Thanks

Comment: Dont use readers is you send both text and image. Just use a DataInputStream.@

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @greenapps thanks, please see my answer below.

Comment: `I create the file and save it with createFile method`. You schould not create the file there as new FileOutputStream will create the file. Moreover we cannot see how you created it there.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to read in binary data but are using a Reader that converts the bytes into characters using some kind of conversion in dependence of the specified charset:

```
inputBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                          new InputStreamReader(input));
```

This opens a reader using the system's charset (e.g. `UTF8` or `cp1252`)

Instead of using Reader and Writer, work with streams, in this case BufferedInputStream and BufferedOutputStream and read/write blocks of `bytes`.

Comment: BufferedReader is used to receive text. Because before image i send some text info. But then i use `BufferedInputStream bufin` that takes InputStream input as parameter to receive image. And actually some images are displayed well but some are not.

Comment: @user3717434 InputStreamReader and BufferedReader both are buffering data into a local buffer, so the inputstream you pass to the BufferedInputStream later on can miss initial bytes of the image because they were read by the readers. Instead of readers/writers you might use DataOutputStream and use writeUTF(value) to send some text. On the client side you use DataInputStream correspondingly

Answer (score 0):

Here i implemented data transfer with DataInput/OutputStream. Data transfer seems ok but now it doesn't display any of the images. Could you tell me what's wrong with my code?(The rest is the same)
I get this error messages, I think i close everything. Why it gives this "hit file end" error?:

> 09-12 20:25:00.005 13426-14473/mattoncino.pollo E/JHEAD: hit file end!!
>
> 09-12 20:25:00.032 13426-14473/mattoncino.pollo W/BitmapFactory: decoder JPEG decode fail!

**Sender Thread**

```
     public class ImageTransferHandler implements Runnable{
        private static final String TAG = "ImageTransferHandler";
        private static final int SERVER_PORT = 8700;
        private Socket socket;
        private Context context;
        private String hostIpAddress;
        private Bar bar;


        @Override
        public void run() {
      
            socket = getSocket(hostIpAddress);
                
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                                                            
            dataOutputStream.writeBoolean(bar.getImageInfo().isCamera());
            Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(bar.getImageInfo().getPath());
            String mimeType = ImagePicker.getMimeType(context, imageUri);
            String ext = mimeType.substring(mimeType.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            if(ext == null) ext = "bmp";
            dataOutputStream.writeUTF(ext);
            
            
            String realPath = ImagePicker.getRealPathFromUri(context, imageUri);
            File imageFile = new File(realPath);
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[(int) imageFile.length()];

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
            fis.read(byteArray);
            fis.close();

            dataOutputStream.writeInt(byteArray.length);
            dataOutputStream.write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

            dataOutputStream.flush();                                  
            dataOutputStream.close();

            closeSocket(socket);
        }
    }
```

**Receiver thread**

```
    public class ImageReceiveHandler implements Runnable{
        private static String TAG = "ImageReceiveHandler";
        private Socket socket;
        private Context context;
        private DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
        private DataInputStream dataInputStream;
        private Bar Bar;


        @Override
        public void run() {

                dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                boolean isCamera = dataInputStream.readBoolean();
                String ext = dataInputStream.readUTF();
                
                File imageFile = ImagePicker.createFile(context, ImagePicker.isExternalStorageWritable(), ext);
                
                if (imageFile != null) {
                    Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
                    Log.d(TAG, "imageUri for received image: " + imageUri.toString());

                    int len = dataInputStream.readInt();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
                    dataInputStream.read(buffer, 0, len);

                    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                    fileOut.write(buffer);
                    fileOut.close();
                
                    Log.d(TAG, "Image is received and saved. File length: " + imageFile.length());

                    ImageInfo info = new ImageInfo(imageUri.toString(), isCamera);
                    Bar = new Bar(info);

                    addNotification(Bar, hostAddress);
                }
                else
                    Log.d(TAG, "ImagePicker.createFile returns NULL");
                    
                dataInputStream.close();
        }
```

**edited**

---

Bar is a class that rappresents my principal object which contains also imageinfo. Have some text other than imageInfo. But i think there is no problem with this class or its usage.

addNotification is just a method that creates a notification, which has an Intent that pass image info to the activity that contains adapter.

ImageInfo is a class to hold image info: a string path and a boolean to flag if image is obtained from camera(this info was used by another method when resizing the image, but for our problem it is irrelevant)

I think file transfer is ok. File size is same at sender and receiver. ext is extension of image.

Sender logs:

> Image len: 23262 Mime type: image/jpeg ext: jpeg

Receiver logs:

> Image is received and saved. image length: 23262 ext: jpeg

```
 final class ImageInfo implements Parcelable, Serializable {
        private String path;
        private final boolean isCamera;

        public ImageInfo(String path, boolean isCamera) {
             this.path = path;
            this.isCamera = isCamera;
        }

        public String getPath() {
            return path;
        }

        public void setPath(String path) {
            this.path = path;
        }

        public boolean isCamera() {
            return isCamera;
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
            parcel.writeString(path);
            parcel.writeByte((byte) (isCamera ? 1 : 0));
        }

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<ImageInfo> CREATOR
                = new Parcelable.Creator<ImageInfo>() {
            public ImageInfo createFromParcel(Parcel in) { return new ImageInfo(in); }

            public ImageInfo[] newArray(int size) { return new ImageInfo[size]; }
        };

        public ImageInfo(Parcel parcel) {
            path = parcel.readString();
            isCamera = parcel.readByte() != 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should not have posted this as an answer. There is no BitmapFactory involved in your code. So why posting such an error? And what does ImageInfo, Bar and addNotification in your code? Please stick to your transfer code. You are not even logging and telling us if the values for 'ext', `len` and file length are correct.

Comment: @greenapps i answered your questions in my answer, please see it.

Comment: I still do not see any relevance in talking about ImageInfo, Bar and addNotification .Take a File Explorer app on your device. Browse to the directory where you saved the image. Then let the Explorer app open or share the picture. Do you see a thumbnail in the explorer? Can the file be displayed by external apps? Check isf the image is saved ok first.

Comment: Files exist but i can't see thumbnail neither . It's always a black/empty file that i see.

Comment: So the transfer is wrong. No need to talk about ImageInfo, Bar and addNotification

Comment: `dataInputStream.read(buffer, 0, len);`. Isnt there a return value?

Comment: @greenapps, from sender log: `Image len: 51617 Mime type: image/jpeg ext: jpeg. fis.read(byteArray) => 51617`. From receiver log: `dataInputStream.readInt() => 51617. dataInputStream.read(buffer, 0, len) => 13032. image length: 51617 ext: jpeg`

Comment: @greenapps, ok i resolved it. Reading all file at once not working. I changed it as suggested in [https://stackoverflow.com/a/12059062/3717434](this) answer(reading in a while loop), now images are displayed without problem. Thanks anyway